# Transposing dataset by creating variables from substr

Tags: sas, transpose, sas-macro

I have a dataset that I need to transpose by a specific design that involves substring.

The original dataset (note: this is just a mock up dataset, in reality, there are 75 nt variables, the transposed notes variable always have an odd suffix, such as nt3, nt5, nt7...):

```
data have;
    input ID $1. NT2 $38. NT3 $4. NT4 $38. NT5 $4.;
    cards;
1   NOTES 12:13:44 03-16-2018 CODE: ABC AML  NOTES 09:13:11 03-12-2018 CODE: OPI TEST
2   NOTES 04:25:09 01-04-2018 CODE: FDS IMD  NOTES 03:25:10 01-09-2018 CODE: FGH TEST
3   NOTES 12:22:49 11-12-2018 CODE: DGH TEST NOTES 08:02:49 11-11-2018 CODE: LKO AML
4   NOTES 22:02:21 01-14-2018 CODE: MKL TEST NOTES 07:02:21 01-10-2018 CODE: LOP IMD
5   NOTES 09:01:36 01-23-2018 CODE: HJK TEST NOTES 09:01:56 01-23-2018 CODE: UIY TEST
;
run;
```

[image]

Transpose by ID to split out time , date, code and notes:

```
ID    time          date   code notes
1    12:13:44    03-16-2018 ABC AML
1    09:13:11    03-12-2018 OPI TEST
2    04:25:09    01-04-2018 FDS IMD
2    03:25:10    01-09-2018 FGH TEST
3    12:22:49    11-12-2018 DGH TEST
3    08:02:49    11-11-2018 LKO AML
4    22:02:21    01-14-2018 MKL TEST
4    07:02:21    01-10-2018 LOP IMD
5    09:01:36    01-23-2018 HJK TEST
5    09:01:56    01-23-2018 UIY TEST
```

After transposing, ID will have multiple levels based on NT variables.

The code I have so far does not yield the desirable output:

```
data note11;
 length note0 $50;
 set note10;

  array t{*} nt:;;
    do _i = 1 to dim(t);
/*make sure notes are not blank*/
      if not missing(t[_i]) then note0 = catx('/',note0,vname(t(_i)));
/*timestamp, date, code*/
      if find(upcase(t[_i]),"NOTES") then do;
     timestamp=substr(left(nt0), index(left(nt0), 'NOTES')+5, 9);                                                                                                              
         date=substr(left(nt0), 15, 10);  
         code = substr(left(nt0), index(left(nt0), 'CODE:')+5);     
      end;

    end;
   drop _i;
run;
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Is the input data a text file?

Comment: It is originally a dataset, I'm just using the 5 cases as a mock-up example

Comment: I don't think your data step produces the example data you expected.  Copy what you posted back into SAS and see what result you get.   Anyway is the issue just how to parse TIME, DATE and CODE from the strings that start with NOTES?

Comment: @Reeza I added an image

Comment: @Tom I added an image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array.

```
data note11;
 set have;

  array _nt{*} nt:;
    do i = 1 to dim(_nt) by 2;

      if not missing(_nt(i)) then do;
       timestamp=input(scan(_nt(i), 2, " "), time8.);                                                                                                              
         date=input(scan(_nt(i), 3, " "), mmddyy10.);  
         code = scan(_nt(i), 5, " ");   
         notes = _nt(i+1);
         output;
      end;

    end;
   drop i nt:;
   format timestamp time. date yymmddd10.;
run;
```

Comment: Sorry, I made an edit, it should be odd suffix for notes variable instead of even..

Comment: so I think , if it's shifted to odd number, the do loop may need to start from 2 ? Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Feel free to adjust for your data as needed. The premise above is correct and works on the data Tom has included. Your data does not read in properly so I cannot test it on that.

Answer (score 2):

So assuming you meant that you had this data.

```
data have;
  input ID $ 1 NT1 $ 2-39 NT2 $ 40-43 NT3 $ 44-81 NT4 $ 82-85;
cards;
1NOTES 12:13:44 03-16-2018 CODE: ABC   AML NOTES 09:13:11 03-12-2018 CODE: OPI   TEST
2NOTES 04:25:09 01-04-2018 CODE: FDS   IMD NOTES 03:25:10 01-09-2018 CODE: FGH   TEST
3NOTES 12:22:49 11-12-2018 CODE: DGH   TESTNOTES 08:02:49 11-11-2018 CODE: LKO   AML
4NOTES 22:02:21 01-14-2018 CODE: MKL   TESTNOTES 07:02:21 01-10-2018 CODE: LOP   IMD
5NOTES 09:01:36 01-23-2018 CODE: HJK   TESTNOTES 09:01:56 01-23-2018 CODE: UIY   TEST
;
```

Which looks very standardized then it should be simple to parse the NT1 and NT3 into three variables you wanted.

```
data want;
  set have;
  length time date 8 code notes $5 ;
  format time tod8. date yymmdd10.;
  notes=nt2;
  time=input(substr(nt1,7),time8.);
  date=input(substr(nt1,17),mmddyy10.);
  code=substr(nt1,33);
  output;
  notes=nt4;
  time=input(substr(nt3,7),time8.);
  date=input(substr(nt3,17),mmddyy10.);
  code=substr(nt3,33);
  output;
  drop nt1-nt4;
run;
```

Results

```
Obs    ID        time          date    code    notes

  1    1     12:13:44    2018-03-16    ABC     AML
  2    1     09:13:11    2018-03-12    OPI     TEST
  3    2     04:25:09    2018-01-04    FDS     IMD
  4    2     03:25:10    2018-01-09    FGH     TEST
  5    3     12:22:49    2018-01-12    DGH     TEST
  6    3     08:02:49    2018-01-11    LKO     AML
  7    4     22:02:21    2018-01-14    MKL     TEST
  8    4     07:02:21    2018-01-10    LOP     IMD
  9    5     09:01:36    2018-01-23    HJK     TEST
 10    5     09:01:56    2018-01-23    UIY     TEST
```

Comment: In reality, there are 75 note variables, I cannot just define them independently, has to be in a loop or array.

Comment: Are the variables alternating like in your example?  Then just define an array and loop over the array increasing the index by 2 each time.  Are all 74 note variables populated?  If not then make the OUTPUT statement conditional.