# Transposing dataset by creating variables from substr with inconsistent pattern

Tags: sas, transpose, sas-macro, data-wrangling

I have a dataset that I need to transpose by a specific design that involves substring with inconsistent column pattern.

The original dataset (note: this is just a mock up dataset, in reality, there are 75 nt variables):

```
data have;
  input ID $ 1 NT2  NT3  NT4  NT5   NT6  ;
cards;
1NOTES 12:13:44 03-16-2018 CODE: ABC   AML NOTES 09:13:11 03-12-2018 CODE: OPI   TEST
2NOTES 04:25:09 01-04-2018 CODE: FDS   IMD NOTES 03:25:10 01-09-2018 CODE: FGH   TEST
3NOTES 12:22:49 11-12-2018 CODE: DGH   TESTNOTES 08:02:49 11-11-2018 CODE: LKO   AML
4NOTES 22:02:21 01-14-2018 CODE: MKL   TESTNOTES 07:02:21 01-10-2018 CODE: LOP   IMD
5NOTES 09:01:36 01-23-2018 CODE: HJK   TESTNOTES 09:01:56 01-23-2018 CODE: UIY   TEST
6NOTES 11:01:06 01-20-2018 CODE: LPO   IMD  TEST    NOTES 10:01:30 01-24-2018 CODE: KLO AML

;
run;
```

[image]

Desired output, transposed by ID to split out time , date, code and notes:

```
ID   time        date      code notes
1    12:13:44    03-16-2018 ABC AML
1    09:13:11    03-12-2018 OPI TEST
2    04:25:09    01-04-2018 FDS IMD
2    03:25:10    01-09-2018 FGH TEST
3    12:22:49    11-12-2018 DGH TEST
3    08:02:49    11-11-2018 LKO AML
4    22:02:21    01-14-2018 MKL TEST
4    07:02:21    01-10-2018 LOP IMD
5    09:01:36    01-23-2018 HJK TEST
5    09:01:56    01-23-2018 UIY TEST
6    11:01:06    01-20-2018 LPO IMD/TEST
6    10:01:30    01-24-2018 KLO AML
```

[image]

The following is my code. It is running indefinitely at the while do loop part

```
data want;
  set have;
  attrib notes length=$50;
     array _nt{*} nt:;
    do i = 1 to dim(_nt) ;
      if not missing(_nt(i)) and index(left(_nt[i]), ' NOTES') then do;
         timestamp=input(scan(_nt(i), 3, " "), time8.0);                                                                                                             
         date=input(scan(_nt(i), 4, " "), mmddyy10.);
         code = substr(_nt[i], index(left(_nt[i]), 'CODE:')+9);
      end;
       /*the while loop is used to concatenate notes that immediately follow the other, but it is running indefinitely*/
       do while(index(left(_nt[i+1]), ' NOTES')=0); 
          notes = catx('/',notes, _nt(i+1));
       end;

    output;
    end;
   drop i nt:;
   format timestamp time8. date mmddyy10.;
run;
```

Note: This is an add-on question to my previous post:
[Transposing dataset by creating variables from substr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74102451/transposing-dataset-by-creating-variables-from-substr/74102847?noredirect=1#comment130836993_74102847)

Comment: How do you expect the condition in the DO WHILE loop to ever become false. You never make any changes to the variables it is testing. And what is it you think that DO WHILE loop is doing for you?

Comment: Why did you repost the the non-working data step from your previous post instead of the corrected one from the answers to your previous question?

Comment: the while loop is part of `do i = 1 to dim(_nt)`, it should be changing with `i`

Comment: Because the dataset changed @Tom , there is a new row added

Comment: Fix the INPUT statement to in the sample data to match the data.

Comment: The value of I is NOT changing the in the DO WHILE loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's make a data step that actually works to create some sample data.
While we are at it let's modify the examples to have more complex examples.  So ID=2 now only has one observation.  And the first observation for ID=5 does not have any strings before the second "NOTES ..." string.

```
data have;
  infile cards dsd truncover;
  input ID $ (NT2-NT6) (:$100.);
cards;
1,NOTES 12:13:44 03-16-2018 CODE: ABC,AML,NOTES 09:13:11 03-12-2018 CODE: OPI,TEST
2,NOTES 04:25:09 01-04-2018 CODE: FDS,IMD
3,NOTES 12:22:49 11-12-2018 CODE: DGH,TEST,NOTES 08:02:49 11-11-2018 CODE: LKO,AML
4,NOTES 22:02:21 01-14-2018 CODE: MKL,TEST,NOTES 07:02:21 01-10-2018 CODE: LOP,IMD
5,NOTES 09:01:36 01-23-2018 CODE: HJK,NOTES 09:01:56 01-23-2018 CODE: UIY,TEST
6,NOTES 11:01:06 01-20-2018 CODE: LPO,IMD,TEST,NOTES 10:01:30 01-24-2018 CODE: KLO,AML
;
```

Now let's just introduce a second DO loop that increments the same counter to look for the following strings to be concatenated.  We will want to remove the extra increment to the index variable that will cause.

```
data want ;
  set have;
  array nt nt: ;
  length time date 8 code $10 notes $100 ;
  format time tod8. date yymmdd10. ;
  do index=1 to dim(nt);
    time=input(scan(nt[index],2,' '),time8.);
    date=input(scan(nt[index],3,' '),mmddyy10.);
    code=scan(nt[index],-1,' ');
    do index=index+1 to dim(nt) while((nt[index] ^=:'NOTES'));
      notes=catx('/',notes,nt[index]);
    end;
    output;
    index=index-1;
    notes=' ';
  end;
  drop index nt: ;
run;
```

Results:

```
Obs    ID        time          date    code    notes

  1    1     12:13:44    2018-03-16    ABC     AML
  2    1     09:13:11    2018-03-12    OPI     TEST
  3    2     04:25:09    2018-01-04    FDS     IMD
  4    3     12:22:49    2018-11-12    DGH     TEST
  5    3     08:02:49    2018-11-11    LKO     AML
  6    4     22:02:21    2018-01-14    MKL     TEST
  7    4     07:02:21    2018-01-10    LOP     IMD
  8    5     09:01:36    2018-01-23    HJK
  9    5     09:01:56    2018-01-23    UIY     TEST
 10    6     11:01:06    2018-01-20    LPO     IMD/TEST
 11    6     10:01:30    2018-01-24    KLO     AML
```

Comment: sorry, I never meant to not respond to your previous request had to leave before rush hour. Thank you so much for the response.